# Multiple instances of TinyMCE in different forms with same name (jQuery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I'm trying to implement an autosave feature that submits several different forms on a page with the same name with TinyMCE'd textareas.

My code:

```
function autoSaveEditForms() {
    $("#auto_save_notify").html("Saving...");
    $("#auto_save_notify").show();
$("form[name=editForm]").each(function() {

    if($('input[name="question"]', this).val() == "" || $('textarea[name="answer"]', this).val() == "")
        return;

    $.post("<?php echo $CONFIG->wwwroot; ?>action/faq/edit?autosave=true", $(this).serialize(), function(data) { 

            $("#auto_save_notify").fadeOut(5000);
        });
});
```

}

The problem is that $('textarea[name="answer"]', this).val() does not change its value if I have two forms on the page.  To clarify, if I have two forms it returns the updated value for one of them, reflecting any changes I make to the textarea, and it returns the original value of the other one (i.e.if I make any changes to one of the textareas then calling val() does not update these changes).

Is this a TinyMCE problem?  Or is it necessary to do this another way?

Thanks.

Update: It works fine if TinyMCE is not used in the textareas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it.
Turns out you cannot access the data in the usual jquery way.  Initialize TinyMCE in this fashion:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  mode : "none",
  theme : "advanced"
});

/* call this function in ajax return text */
function makeTinyMCE(faqid) {
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'answer'+faqid);

}
```

Then grab the text in this way:

```
tinyMCE.editors['answer'+faqid].getContent()
```

Answer (score 1):

Its probably not a good idea to have two forms with the same name. Add a unique identifier to each form:

```
<form name="myform1">
</form>

<form name="myform2">
</form>
```

Code the event that triggers this to pass the formid it lives in:

```
function autoSaveEditForms($formid)
```

Comment: hi, i tried giving the forms and all of there elements unique ids and unique names to no avail.  any other ideas?  I'm up the creek on this one.. I guess it's a tinyMCE problem.

Comment: This should allow you to access the different forms
document.myform1...
document.myform2...

Try the javascript debugger in firefox (CTL + Shift + J) and look at the error message.